# Applying function to entire data-set x number of times for each observation

Tags: r, simulation, nested-loops

I am trying to apply a function to a simulated data set (the easy part), though I have to apply this function x number of times. My overall goal in this project is to simulate abundances of species over time for many populations over many years. In this example we will work with 15 species over thirty years for one community.

I have used a function and called it:

```
curve<-function(Ao,m,r,a,g){(Ao*((((x-m)/r)+(a/(a+g)))^a)*((1-(((x-m)/r)+(a/(a+g))))^g))/(((a/(a+g))^a)*((1-(a/(a+g)))^g))}
x<-seq(1,365, by=14) #this is the number of times that I get sampled abundances, and is included in the function
```

I then run a loop and create an abundance table, along with a table giving me the values of each variable.

```
TotSpecies<-15  
Community<-30

for(n in 1:TotSpecies){
  Ao<-rlnorm(TotSpecies,3,2)    
  m<-sample(seq(min(x)+5:max(x)-5),TotSpecies)  
  r<-runif(TotSpecies,min=0,max=max(x)) 
  a<-(runif(TotSpecies,min=.1,max=4))       
  g<-(runif(TotSpecies,min=.1,max=4))       
}
Abundance <- matrix(0,nrow=length(x),ncol=TotSpecies)
colnames(Abundance) = c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5","Sp6","Sp7","Sp8","Sp9","Sp10","Sp11","Sp12","Sp13","Sp14","Sp15")
  for(L in 1:TotSpecies){
    Abundance[,L] <- curve(Ao[L],m[L],r[L],a[L],g[L])
}

#Alter matrix to removed NANs and replace with zeroes
Abundance.NA<-is.na(Abundance)
Abundance[Abundance.NA]<-0      #this makes Abundance have 0's where abundance is NaN
Pres.Abs<-Abundance
Pres.Abs[Pres.Abs>0]<-1         #presence-absence matrix

#creates a data frame with the values of each variable
Species<-1:TotSpecies
Year<-rep(1,TotSpecies)
year1data<-data.frame(Species,Year,Ao,m,r,a,g)
```

At this point, I only have data of abundances for one year and one community. Now I want to simulate for this community over thirty years, altering the abundances of species sequentially from year to year by adding error.

```
TotSpeciesData <- do.call(
  rbind, #bind the table by rows
  lapply(    #applying the function in list form
    split(year1data, year1data$Species),   #splits data into groups by species
    function(data) 
      with(
        data, 
        data.frame(Species=Species, Year=1:Community, Ao=c(Ao, Ao + cumsum(rnorm((TotSpecies-1),0,2))),m=m, r=r, a=a, g=g) #data frame is Species, Year, 
        ) ) ) 
  TotSpeciesData$Ao[TotSpeciesData$Ao<0]<-0             #any values less than 0 go to 0
TotSpeciesData<-TotSpeciesData[order(TotSpeciesData$Year),] #orders the data frame by Year
```

This is now a data frame with each given variable for each species for each year. Now I do not know how to apply the function to this table and create an abundance table that has all fifteen species for the thirty years.

I started off thinking that a nested loop would be the best instead of trying to use the apply function because the apply function could not handle me trying to run the function x number or times (or am I wrong in this??).

```
TotSpeciesAbundance<-matrix(0,nrow=Community*length(x),ncol=TotSpecies)
colnames(TotSpeciesAbundance) = c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5","Sp6","Sp7","Sp8","Sp9","Sp10","Sp11","Sp12","Sp13","Sp14","Sp15")
Year<-rep(1:Community, each=length(x))
TotSpeciesAbundance<-cbind(TotSpeciesAbundance,Year)

for(p in 1:450){  
  for(j in 1:TotSpecies){
    Ao<-TotSpeciesData$Ao
    m<-TotSpeciesData$m
    r<-TotSpeciesData$r
    a<-TotSpeciesData$a
    g<-TotSpeciesData$g
    TotSpeciesAbundance[,j]<- curve(Ao[j],m[j],r[j],a[j],g[j])
```

}
}

I have tried a number of different ways to alter the double loop, though cannot find a way to get it to work. This may be a bit amateur, but can anyone help in this ?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question. In your first `for`, you run through the loop 15 times, and just overwrite the result each time. So you are only using the results of the 15th run, surely that is not what you intended (or you wouldn't need a `for`). Also, `seq(min(x)+5:max(x)-5)` is almost certainly not doing what you wanted, because `:` has precedence over binary `+`. You probably meant `(seq(min(x)+5):(max(x)-5))`. Also, writing out the `curve` function would be very helpful.

Comment: I edited the above to include the function. What I am trying to do with the initial 'for' loop is to randomly create values for each species 1 through 15. This starts off my community and then I plan to alter this community by changing Ao yearly. Thank you for finding the error in the 'seq'.

Comment: Your `for` loop is exactly equivalent to running the body once. Try it. Also, in `TotSpeciesData`, you only generate 15 values of `Ao` for 30 years, so `Ao` is repeated for every `Species`. To see what I mean, examine `TotSpeciesData[TotSpeciesData$Species==1 & TotSpeciesData$Year %in% c(1,2,16,17),]`. Surely this is not what you intended.

Comment: You are correct. This is not what I want, though I do not know how to make it so that I pull from the    TotSpeciesData and create an abundance data table. What I have tried to do in the   TotSpeciesData loop is make all variables the same from year to year, but add some random error to the abundance    Ao=c(Ao, Ao + cumsum(rnorm((TotSpecies-1),0,2))).

Comment: I also now see what you mean about the 15 values. Ugh :/

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what you want, but I can make a guess. Your second `for` loop contains the same problem as your first one: you overwrite the same `data.frame` 450 times. I think what you intended is something like this:

```
# Bug fix: make TotSpeciesAbundance a data.frame so with works
TotSpeciesAbundance<-data.frame(TotSpeciesAbundance)
# Make a storage list beforehand.
big.list<-list()
for(p in 1:450){  
  TotSpeciesAbundance <- matrix(ncol=length(x),nrow=TotSpecies)
  for(j in 1:TotSpecies){
    TotSpeciesAbundance[,j]<- with(TotSpeciesData,curve(Ao[j],m[j],r[j],a[j],g[j]))
  }
  big.list[[p]] <- TotSpeciesAbundance
}
```

But, conveniently, you can replace the inner `for`:

```
for(p in 1:450) {  
  big.list[[p]] <- with(TotSpeciesAbundance,mapply(curve,Ao,m,r,a,g))
}
```

Which makes it quite clear that you were not only rerunning the thing 450 times, but you were doing it with exactly the same thing. You could replace this with:

```
replicate(450,with(TotSpeciesAbundance,mapply(curve,Ao,m,r,a,g)),simplify=FALSE)
```

I am guessing you want to add a bit of noise or something each time, but I can't figure out exactly what you want. Perhaps if you clearly explained what you mean by an abundance matrix, and give a small example of what the output data would look like.

Comment: I want to make an abundance matrix in exactly the same format as the first one in the code titled `Abundance`. The code that I would use to set up the matrix is:  `TotSpeciesAbundance<-matrix(0,nrow=Community*length(x),ncol=TotSpecies)
colnames(TotSpeciesAbundance) = c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5","Sp6","Sp7","Sp8","Sp9","Sp10","Sp11","Sp12","Sp13","Sp14","Sp15")  
Year<-rep(1:Community, each=length(x))  
TotSpeciesAbundance<-cbind(TotSpeciesAbundance,Year)`

Comment: I tried to use the code that you provided though I was unable to get any of them to work. I got errors stating:  `Error in TotSpeciesAbundance[, j] <- with(TotSpeciesData, curve(Ao[j],  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` on the first part.  `Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'logical'` on the second part. and `Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one` on the last part.

Comment: Also you are correct in assuming that I am trying to add noise to Ao in a stepwise manner

Comment: I fixed the problem, but admittedly, the code just replicates what you did in a more efficient manner. I still don't really understand what you want.

Comment: The reason why I am having such difficulty is that the function that I am trying to use has variables that differ in length, specifically x varies compared to all other variables. What I want to do is run my function `curve` using the vector `x` and the table `TotSpeciesData` for all other variables. Each observation of `TotSpeciesData` should be run `x` times. The only thing that changes in `TotSpeciesData` is `Ao`, which I added some noise to. The output for the function should look exactly like the table `Abundance` but for 30 years rather than 1. Does that make more sense?